# Set VIM to open files in "read-only" mode by default?

Tags: vim, readonly

Straightforward question here and I can't make it any simpler than the title:

How do I set VIM to open files in "read-only" mode by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

add

```
set ro
```

to your `.vimrc`.

Also: commonly, you can type `view filename` instead of `vim filename` and it will open vim in readonly mode.

Comment: This isn't working in my `.vimrc` file, which is otherwise exceedingly simple. I have `set ai ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 hlsearch nu rnu nowrap et ro`. The other options seem to take effect, such as `nu`. Any thoughts?

Comment: An important note: `view` will open `vi`, not `vim`, in read-only mode. This is a huge difference if you still want the nice features of `vim` such as syntax coloring that you have defined in `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 28):

`vim -R filename` will open file in read-only mode.

this still will allow you to modify buffers, if you want to prohibit this - there's an option `:set nomodifiable`, to allow modification use `:set modifiable`.
There's short version for those who in hurry,`:set ma` and `:set noma` does the opposite.

Answer (score 9):

Not directly the answer to the question, but to automatically open a file as read-only if a swap file is already present, add following line to your `vimrc`:

```
autocmd SwapExists * let v:swapchoice = "o"
```

Meaning: if a swap already exists, the usual question

```
E325: 
Found a swap file by the name "..."
Swap file already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

will be automatically responded with 'o' (Open Read-Only).

Answer (score 4):

Can be done using `view`.

```
view [filename]
```

Comment: `view` does not display any syntax highlighting, best I can tell. Any way to turn this on?

Comment: (in normal mode) type `:syntax on`

Comment: That works. Any way to turn this on by default? Best I can figure at the moment is a shell alias along the lines of `alias view="view -c 'syntax on'"`.

Comment: I have `syntax on` setting in .vimrc, it works when using `view [filename]` in my case..

Comment: Interesting. Does not work for me. `vim` displays syntax highlighting but not `view`, so they're obviously not reading the same vimrc. (Or some other setting is interfering.)